# My Xbox headset just died. What are my options?

Tags: xbox-360

After 2 and a half years, the headset that came with my Xbox finally died.

So what are my options to replace it? Can I plug in any USB Headset in the USB ports? Could I use the kinect microphone for chat? How can I get another headset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Kinect microphone for chatting. This does mean that anyone else talking in the same place as you will be heard by the other players, of course.

A normal USB headset will not work, since the voice chat is transmitted over the cable from the controller to the headset. Aside from buying another Microsoft headset, a variety of other companies produce headsets that work with the Xbox - [Turtle Beach](http://www.turtlebeach.com/) and [Astro Gaming](http://www.astrogaming.com/) being two options.

As long as the headset lists that it works with the Xbox 360, you'll be fine.